# Condition based returns for a toString()

Tags: java, tostring

Here is my toString

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return
              "Name: " + name +
              " Date of birth: " + dateOfBirth + " Serial number: " + userSerialNumber +
              " Gold Status: " + if(goldStatus == true){ return " Gold" } else {return "Standard"};
  }
```

The last phrase is what I've tried, but I get a "java: illegal start of expression" compiler error. How do I make this code compilable?

Comment: You are going to want to use a conditional statement instead of an if statement if you are integrating it into a string. Use (goldStatus ? " Gold" : "Standard") instead of the if.

Comment: @Nicolas125841 Never compare booleans to `true`.

Comment: Maybe it should be added (since you are probably new to coding) that you can not put `return` inside a `return`. If you use return anywhere in your code it will return a value or an object and thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return
        "Name: " + name +
        " Date of birth: " + dateOfBirth + " Serial number: " + userSerialNumber +
        " Gold Status: " + (goldStatus ? " Gold" : "Standard");
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I have to wait 10 minutes before accepting your answer but I will do so once I can. That looks like much cleaner code.